# I need a software that will help me to create an diagram of a structure of my application

Tags: database, networking, drawing, diagram

I need a software that might help me about drawing/creating something like this: 
[image]

That's what I've found in my faculty book, and I need to create my own diagram of structure of my application, that might look something like that but more extended, I really don't know any software that might help me achieve this?

If anyone know I would appreaciate that so much!

Thanks guys

Comment: What OS should it run on? What is your price limit when it comes to paid software?

Comment: Related question: [*Software for drawing network diagrams*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/45509/3442)

Comment: I always use the freeware [Yed](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed) for this. Sorry, I have a a lousy flu & am not up to a good answer, but Yed has been mentioned many times on this site, so check out some of [those answers](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=yed)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [LucidChart Network Diagram Software](https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/examples/network_diagram_software), I think this will do it for your case.

[image: Scene 1]

Comment: It would be helpful to include at least the name of "this" in the answer, so mobile visitors have a chance to see what this answer is talking about without opening the link.

Comment: oops, yeah, that's my mistake..

Comment: Do you know how much it costs? I can't see it on the web site, but it does mention a free trial, so I guess we have to pay.

Answer (score 2):

Online in your browser via [draw.io](https://www.draw.io/?splash=0&libs=network;general;advanced;cisco)

[image]

Think you could also use PacketTracer to do the drawing, but I think that is download restricted to cisco members/users/folks