# Tool for modeling software architectures

Tags: software-development, modeling

> OS: Doesn't matter, I'd prefer Linux tho.
>
> Budget: prefering something free as its the only thing I need to virtualize

I got something like below. The picture is my miserable try to show my kubernetes cluster architecture. I need a tool which got some basic figures like boxes or frameworks and similar to clean this mess up and make it way more detailled. Are there any recommendations?

[image]

> **Some example screens of what I am having in mind:**

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

[image: pic3]

Comment: Is it really about software development? To me it looks like a network diagram and deployment diagram.

Comment: Does https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/46300/i-need-a-software-that-will-help-me-to-create-an-diagram-of-a-structure-of-my-ap answer your question?

Comment: It's more or less a deployment diagram. But all these components are running within a server, so probably there is something which could fit my needs more, but its getting closer :). draw.io seems to be nice, using the zones like inside and outside etc.

Comment: Would a [UML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) solution be of any use? Which operating system? Must it be [tag:gratis], or do you have a budget?

Comment: I already thought about using UML for it, as it would at least provide most of the functions I am thinking about. I am using linux (manjaro, so got access to AUR packages). I'd prefer free, as I only need it to do like 3 models.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.predictiveanalyticstoday.com/open-source-free-unified-modeling-language-uml-tools/#whatarethefeaturesofunifiedmodelinglanguageumlsoftware). Personally, I recommend very popular [PlantUML](http://plantuml.com/) (and think that [BoUML](https://www.bouml.fr/) is worth a look at), but that's because I love tools where I provide ASCII text and they build diagrams (because a lot of that ASCII text comes from my debug trace).